# Inspect PostgreSQL constraints with Beekeeper-Studio

Tags: postgresql, constraints, editor

I was wondering if Beekeeper-Studio editor provides a functionality to inspect database constraints or if I have to run every time a little SQL script to inspect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot even drop or truncate a table in beekeeper, atleast not in my version (3.6.2)

Comment: yes, thanks can you recommend a more powerful db editor?

Comment: Im currently using [HeidiSql](https://www.heidisql.com/) , it has it flaws and looks dated.  

I prefer it over Oracles workbench. Hopefully BeeKeeper will continue to evolve, it shows some potential..